# Scala: Pattern matching a generic case class for "concrete" cases

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching

let's say I have:

```
sealed trait Data
final case class TextData()  extends Data
final case class ImageData() extends Data
final case class MetaData[D <: Data](data: D) extends Data
```

I want to pattern match Data objects. I have defined:

```
def getDataTypeName(data: Data): String ={
    data match {
        case TextData()=>"text"
        case ImageData()=>"image"
        //MetaData(MetaData(_))=>"metaMeta1"  //a
        case _:MetaData[MetaData[_]]=>"metaMeta2"  //b
        //case MetaData(data:Data)=>"meta"+ getDataTypeName(data) //c
        //MetaData(TextData(_))=>"metaMeta1"  //d
        case MetaData(_)=>"meta"
    }
}
```

I want to be able to see if my data is a meta-metadata, meta-TextData, etc. 
Line `a` give me an error, saying:

> constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;  found   :
>   inst$A$A.MetaData[D]  required: A$A115.this.Data case
>   MetaData(MetaData(_))=>"metaMeta1"

I would prefer to have something resembling line `a`. alternatively something like line `c` would be nice too.

I also tried line `b`. This one generates some warnings:

> non-variable type argument A$A115.this.MetaData[*] in
>   type pattern A$A115.this.MetaData[A$A115.this.MetaData[*]] is
>   unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
>               case *:MetaData[MetaData[*]]=>"metaMeta"
>                      ^

I get this warning for both `MetaData[_]s`. My understanding is that the said pattern is reduced to _ after type erasure which is consistent with my test results.

I therefore want to know if there is a way of matching against `MetaMetaData`, `MetaTextData` ,`MetaMetaMetaData` etc.

Alternatively, is my design using sealed class in a way they shouldn't be used? What alternative design would you suggest?

Comment: i assume that match against MetaData, and then match again to check the inner class is not your ideal solution? ```data match { case Metadata(x) => x match { ... } }```

Comment: I guess I would be happy with that too. In fact I did try doing something similar (line c), but couldn't get the syntax right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a change to the `MetaData()` definition to make this work.

```
sealed trait Data
final case class TextData()  extends Data
final case class ImageData() extends Data
final case class MetaData(data: Data) extends Data

def printType(data: Data): String = data match {
  case TextData()=>"text"
  case ImageData()=>"image"
  case MetaData(d)=>"meta:" + printType(d)
}

val md = MetaData( MetaData(TextData()) )
printType(md)  // res0: String = meta:meta:text
```

Comment: oh I see. That makes me think: Is there any real difference between the previous definition and this definition in terms of how the compiler sees it?

Comment: Well, obviously the compiler sees them differently since this won't compile under the original definition.  Would it make a difference in your code? Probably not.

Comment: I guess the difference is that in the old definition data was actually interfaced with, as the subtype that it was whereas in the new format, it is just an instance of the base class. But does that actually matter? not really.

Answer (score 0):

```
  sealed trait Data
  final case class TextData()  extends Data
  final case class ImageData() extends Data
  final case class MetaData[D <: Data](data: D) extends Data
```

and

```
def getDataTypeName(data: Data): String ={
    data match {
      case TextData()=>"text"
      case ImageData()=>"image"
      case MetaData(MetaData(_))=> "metaMeta1" 
      case MetaData(TextData())=> "textMeta1"  
      case MetaData(ImageData())=> "imgMeta1"  
    }
  }
```

testing on REPL:

```
scala> getDataTypeName(TextData())
res1: String = text

scala> getDataTypeName(MetaData(TextData()))
res2: String = textMeta1

scala> getDataTypeName(MetaData(MetaData(TextData())))
res3: String = metaMeta1
```